# The question asks to print the sum of all integers in an array. Why cant I run the following code?

Tags: c++, arrays, sum

The program crashes after asking for array values. I am new to programming. Please help me out!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int number_of_elements;
    cin >> number_of_elements;
    int sum_of_array = 0;
    vector <int> ar(number_of_elements);
    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_elements; i++){
       cin >> ar[i];
       sum_of_array += ar[i];
    }
    cout << sum_of_array;
    return sum_of_array;
}
```

Comment: Write return 0; instead of  return sum_of_array; And also cout << sum_of_array << '\n';

Comment: What does "crashes" mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cout` to print out the answer, but `int main()` should **ALWAYS** return 0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    
    int number_of_elements;
    cin >> number_of_elements;
    int sum_of_array = 0;
    vector <int> ar(number_of_elements);
    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_elements; i++){
       cin >> ar[i];
       sum_of_array += ar[i];
    }
    cout << sum_of_array;
    return 0;
}
```